# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio 2014

Tags: ctp, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to install support for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps on Visual Studio 14 CTP? There is a template (Install Multi-Device Hybrid App tools for Apache Cordova) but when you try to load it, it fails with following error:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsipSupport.PlaceholderProject, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.

When I tried to install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675), I got an error that said I need to install Visual Studio 2013 Update 3. Since I have VS14 CTP, I think that it should work.

Does anybody have an idea what to do? Also, whole setup is on Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Comment: @priyank will you hold on your edits and check [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276911/self-decided-tag-burnination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i installed in [visual studio 2013 update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43721) , and it's works for me , so you have to install vs 2013 with update 3

Comment: So no way to run on VS 2014?

Comment: in the microsoft download center they wrote ,"Note: You must have Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 installed" , so I think that there is no support for visual studio 2014 yet

Comment: Guess so. We'll have to wait.

Comment: Multi Device Hybrid Apps currently not supported on Visual Studio "14". We're hoping to land an update soon though. You can follow the team on @VSCordovaTools for news and updates.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the extension currently works with only VS2013 Update 3. It's one thing to recognize with CTPs (Community Technology Previews) that they represent "work in progress" and don't represent final features or compatibilities.